# When running X remotely via Cygwin why are my fonts ugly

Tags: cygwin

Is there any way to pretty anti-aliased fonts to work on cygwin X server?

[image]

Basically I want the vim screen on the left to look like the pretty vim screen on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I know this isn't a *direct* answer, but [have you considered running Xming instead](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)?  With Xming you at least get TTF support, and I've used it to connect remotely with no font anti-alias issues.  My experience has been, pretty much, "if it looks like that on the screen on the server, it also looks like that on my workstation".

Comment: The funny thing is to work around this annoyance, I ended up configuring GVim on windows and shared the dirs Im editing via samba so its all working pretty nicely now without needing an X server

Comment: This is not a valid solution: Xming 6.9.0.31 (latest free) has the same problem.

Comment: I found that adding '-dpi 101' to the XMing shortcut helped a lot - for some reason with the standard dpi of 96, all the fonts seem too small in XMing.

Comment: I found kybernetikos's suggestion of using -dpi 101 on XMing to be extremely helpful.

Comment: It should be noted that `-dpi 100` works for Cygwin/X as well...