# getting Ubuntu-quality fonts / configuration under Cygwin/X

Tags: ubuntu, xming, cygwin-x

I have Cygwin/X installed on a Win7 box. I also have an Ubuntu VM running on the Win7 host.

If I do the following:

1. Start Xming on the Win7 box
2. Start mate-terminal under Cygwin/X

then mate-terminal starts up with very crappy-looking fonts and a blinking cursor.
(I'm using "Monospace 10" in mate-terminal.)

If I then do:

3. Use putty to ssh into the Ubuntu VM (fowarding the X connection)
4. Run gnome-settings-daemon on the Ubuntu VM

then the fonts in mate-terminal suddenly become much better looking and the cursor stops blinking (probably because I've configured it that way in Ubuntu.)

Question:

How can I get the better-looking fonts and the ability to set cursor-blinks option for mate-terminal under Cygwin/X without having to run the Ubuntu VM?

FWIW, I have Xming-fonts-7-5-0-4 installed.

Update: Starting Xming with '-dpi 101' as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/21543/when-running-x-remotely-via-cygwin-why-are-my-fonts-ugly) helps, but the fonts are still not anti-aliased.

Update: Figured out the cursor blink problem... added this:

```
    <entry name="cursor_blink_mode" mtime="1346104804" type="string">
            <stringvalue>off</stringvalue>
    </entry>
```

to the file `~/.mateconf/apps/mate-terminal/profiles/Default/%mateconf.xml`
when mateconfd is not running.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create the configuration files for GTK2 and GTK3 in the Cygwin environment, in order to make the applications load and use them, as there is not a settings-manager running on Cygwin.